# why we match secret key with databse secret key when we can get user id from A-token easily

Tags: java, authentication, cookies, authorization, session-cookies

I want to ask that why we use authorization in our social netwroking sites. When we can get user id from A-token then why we use secret key to match with database stored secret key to get user id from there.

Please help me

Comment: What do you mean with an A-token?

Comment: when session is created then A-token and coockie is passed to browser